# Sharing URI IOS Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, uri, sharing

I used this code snippet to share an URI from my app.

```
NSObject[] activitiesItems = { 
                                new NSString(post.Title),
                                new NSUrl(post.URL)
                             };

var activityController = new UIActivityViewController(activitiesItems, null);
PresentViewController(activityController, true, null);
```

and I got a good result.
But when I finished sharing my URI with which app I want, when I come back I have my header and footer, of the viewcontroller where I shared, disappeard. It looks like app is fullscreen.

If can be a hint, my viewcontroller is embed in a navigationcontroller.

Can anybody help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code looks correct.  Check if setting your viewcontroller as RootViewController at somewhere .

Comment: I cannot really understand what you mean